# convert regular expression to be more specific

Tags: .net, regex

I have this regex

```
<a(.*?)person\=([0-9]*)(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>
```

which is matching any anchor with a person query string with a numeric value

I need to refine this so it matches an anchor to a page called entry.aspx with the querystring value

IE

```
<a href="entry.aspx?val1=1&person=12" target="_blank">test</a>
<a href="entry.aspx?person=1&val2=hello">more testing</a>
```

are matches

```
<a href="entry.aspx?val1=1&val2=12" target="_blank">test</a>
<a href="noentry.aspx?person=1&val2=hello">more testing</a>
```

are not

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Mandatory comment: You don't want to parse HMTL with regular expressions. Use a [proper parser](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Besides @Tomalaks comment: when asking such types of questions it is always better to provide sample input and expected output, as it can be hard to guess what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Basti - I don't need output but I have included some examples of expected input.

Comment: @Tomalak - You are correct. But thats they way it is, I dont have time to rip apart the whole project.

Comment: "I don't have time to write proper code" is the worst excuse. It's the explanation why so much horrible code exists.

Comment: If you want to pay me to do it properly that's fine, because my boss doesnt. Should I send my paypal details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick shot:

```
<a href=\"entry.aspx\?.*(?=person).*>.*<\/a>
```

See the [example@regex101](http://regex101.com/r/hQ8jR6).
Explanation: using a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) this expression only matches when `person` comes after `entry.aspx` and before the `>`.

Comment: @DavidB i switched from gskinner to [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)/[debuggex.com](http://debuggex.com) some time ago, because in some scenarios  the underlying enginge from gskinner seems to differ from the JS/PCRE-engines, leading to wrong results. At both mentioned tools you have the ability to switch the engine, which is - imo - perfect.

Comment: Nice tip - much obliged

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific , you can give :

```
<a href=["]entry[.]aspx[?]([a-zA-Z0-9]+[=][a-zA-Z0-9]+[&]?)*person[=]([0-9]+)([&]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+[=][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*["]([ ]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+[=][_"a-zA-Z0-9]+)*>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*<\/a>
```